# How to calculate orientation when a ray hits a quad?

Tags: augmented-reality, linear-algebra, arcore, raycasting, directxmath

I know how to determine where a ray hit a quad but I don't know how to determine the orientation at the hit position.

ArCore describes the [HitResult pose](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/HitResult#getHitPose()) for a plane as:

> HitResult.getHitPose()
>
> Returns the pose of the intersection between a ray and detected real-world geometry. The position is the location in space where the ray intersected the geometry. The orientation is a best effort to face the user's device, and its exact definition differs depending on the Trackable that was hit.
>
> Plane: X+ is perpendicular to the cast ray and parallel to the plane, Y+ points along the plane normal (up, for HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING planes), and Z+ is parallel to the plane, pointing roughly toward the user's device.

Note that a Pose is a position (Vector3) and an orientation (quaternion).

I'm currently using [DirectX::TriangleTests::Intersects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxcollision/nf-directxcollision-intersects) to calculate the position where the ray hits the quad. Calculating Y+ is easy by using the plane's normal but I don't know how to calculate X+ and Z+.